# How can I multiply elements in a string using python and store resulting string in a variable?

Tags: python

Here is the Problem needed to be solved:

This problem requires you to create a output string from input string such that for every character in input string, there are three same characters in output string.('Hello' is the input sting)
("HHHeeellllllooo" is the desired output.)

This is what I have tried:

```
input_string = "Hello"
output_string = ""
N = 3

for i in input_string:
    strings = i * 3
    print(strings, end = "")
```

How can I store the 'expanded' string to output_string?

Comment: How do you store _anything_ to a variable?

Comment: "How can I store the 'expanded' string to output_string?" Well, when you compute `strings = i * 3`, can you think of a rule that tells you what you should do with that value and the existing `output_string`, in order to update `output_string`? What English words would you use to describe that process? Now, what happens when you use that information to try to look up an answer with a search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing each segment `strings`, you can just concatenate them into one big string `output_string` and then print it.

```py
input_string = "Hello"
output_string = ""
N = 3

for i in input_string:
    strings = i * 3
    output_string += strings

print(output_string)
```

`output_string += strings` is equivalent to `output_string = output_string + strings`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I knew, inside the loop you only need to assign the value of by     `output_string += i * 3` instead of `strings = i * 3`. In this case you are keeping the pervious value, beside that you are also adding the new value to the pervious.
the new code will be like:

```
input_string = "Hello"
output_string = ""
N = 3

for i in input_string:
    output_string += i * 3
print(output_string, end = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing it, add it to `output_string`.

```
input_string = "Hello"
output_string = ""
N = 3

for i in input_string:
    output_string += i * 3 # means same thing as output_string = output_string + i*3

print(output_string) # Output: HHHeeellllllooo
```

The key point here, is that you can use `+` to concatenate strings:

```
a = "Hello, "
b = "World!"

a + b # Output: Hello, World!
```